# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.318.21''

Tags: python, string, csv, error-handling, floating-point

i'm trying to convert data type from object to float, however when I try to convert it shows the error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.318.21'
```

Here is the code:

```
profkes_na=profkes_df.fillna(0)
profkes_decimal=profkes_na.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
profkes_float=profkes_decimal.astype('float')
```

Thank you.

Comment: How can a float have two decimals ?
Error output clearly tells that it's unable to convert string with two decimals to float, in your logic you need to get rid of last decimal

Comment: this isn't a valid float, hence the error

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks !, but still it should not contain two ',' or '.'

Answer (score 1):

change : `profkes_decimal=profkes_na.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()`
to : `profkes_decimal=profkes_na.stack().str.replace(',','').unstack()`

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from the question what modules are being used. In pure Python one could do this:

```
s = '1.318.21'

def asfloat(s):
    if (ndp := s.count('.')) > 1:
        s = s.replace('.', '', ndp-1)
    return float(s)

print(asfloat(s))
```